# How to properly configure lighttpd in Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, webserver, lighttpd

Recently I started working with "lighttpd" webserver to host local webserver to place some files. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 machine within the docker container. I am following this guide [lighttpd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/lighttpd). I have installed lighttpd package using `apt install lighttpd`. The `lighttpd.conf` looks like:

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_indexfile",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_redirect",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 81
server.bind                 = "localhost"
server.tag                  = "lighttpd"

# strict parsing and normalization of URL for consistency and security
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_http-parseoptsDetails
# (might need to explicitly set "url-path-2f-decode" = "disable"
#  if a specific application is encoding URLs inside url-path)
server.http-parseopts = (
  "header-strict"           => "enable",# default
  "host-strict"             => "enable",# default
  "host-normalize"          => "enable",# default
  "url-normalize-unreserved"=> "enable",# recommended highly
  "url-normalize-required"  => "enable",# recommended
  "url-ctrls-reject"        => "enable",# recommended
  "url-path-2f-decode"      => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-2f-reject"      => "enable",
  "url-path-dotseg-remove"  => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-dotseg-reject"  => "enable",
 #"url-query-20-plus"       => "enable",# consistency in query string
)

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.conf.pl"
include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/*.conf"

#server.compat-module-load   = "disable"
server.modules += (
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_dirlisting",
        "mod_staticfile",
)
```

Also I have a simple HTML file in `/var/www/html/` to display `Hello World!`

But when I start lighttpd using `/etc/init.d/lighttpd start` I get:

```
(network.c.311) can't bind to socket: 127.0.0.1:81 Address already in use
```

And when I open browser (ex, chrome) and launch `localhost:81`, it shows `This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.`

I tried with `/etc/init.d/lighttpd stop` and started again but it results in the same error.

When I do `netstat -ntulp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:81            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I expected a PID should have been assigned to `lighttpd`

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how can it be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: If you’re already using Docker, why not just `docker pull sebp/lighttpd`? So long as the host is properly secured, [this is all you need](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/lighttpd) 

Comment: Hello @matigo, Yes, I saw this. But this will create a new container right? I want to place files from my existing container.. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Is there a reason you insist on using `lighttpd`? You could consider using `nginx` instead, which is more widely supported

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the port `81` is already used by some other application.
To see `PID/Program` you should use `sudo netstat -ntulp`.

You can also try to change `lighttpd` port to something else e.g. `83` or `88`...

Regards